# What is the highest order of infinity?

Tags: infinity

I know there are countably infinite sets and uncountably infinity sets. I would like to know, what is the highest order of infinity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem

Comment: There isn’t one; as the link in the previous comment shows, if you have a set $A$ of some cardinality, its power set $\wp(A)$ is a set of strictly larger cardinality. It’s like asking what’s the biggest positive integer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, that makes sense! I wish you well.

Comment: @ktm5124: You’re welcome!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Infinite